# Constructores estáticos

Tags: java

Realizo una clase estática en java para conectarme a base de datos, hasta donde se el constructor estático se ejecuta una sola vez he creado clases estáticas pero en C# ahora intento hacerlo con java y tengo un problema con la sintaxis. Este es el codigo

```
public  class Querys {

  static class BD extends Querys{

    public static  BD()
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Pero netBeans me indica que  la palabra static es invalida, alguien sabe por que? o ya no es necesaria y se ejecutara una sola vez ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> netBeans me indica que la palabra static es invalida, alguien sabe por que?

En Java, los constructores **no pueden ser estáticos** porque no lo necesita. Aunque la clase sea estática, el constructor no debe ser estático.

El modificador `static` se puede entender como que el campo o método le pertenece a la clase y no a la instancia. Por ello, si el constructor fuese estático, significa que no podrías utilizar el constructor para crear instancias (según lo que interpreta el compilador).

Remueve dicho modificador para que el código compile:

```
public  class Querys {
    static class BD extends Querys{
        public static  BD() {
        }
    }
}
```

> ya no es necesaria y se ejecutara una sola vez?

Esto no significa que se ejecutará solo una vez. Si lo que quieres es crear el patrón singleton, mi recomendación es **no lo hagas**. Si aún así quieres crearlo, aquí te dejo un fragmento de código que resuelve tu problema:

```
public final class MiSingleton {

    private MiSingleton() {
        //...
    }

    private static class Loader {
        static final MiSingleton INSTANCE = new MiSingleton();
    }

    public static MiSingleton getInstance() {
        return Loader.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia

Answer (score 1):

En java no hay constructores estáticos. Debes usar un bloque estático si quieres que un código se ejecute  al cargar la clase.

```
static {

// colocar tu codigo aquí
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Querys {

    private static Querys singletonQuerys = new Querys();

    public static Querys instancia() {
        return singletonQuerys;
    }

    private int miAttr1;
    private double miAttr2;

    // constructor privado
    private Querys() {
        // inicializar y crear cosas
    }

    public int getAttr1() {
        return miAttr1;
    }

    // Otras cosas....  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En java no existe clase estatica, lo que sí existe son constructores, metodos y atributos estaticos. Para implementar un constructor estatico y que este inicialize por ejemplo un atributo estatico seria algo asi:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

public  class ConexionDAO {
    public static EntityManager em;
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private static final String PU = "HibernateJpaPU";
    static
    {
        ConexionDAO.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(ConexionDAO.PU);
        ConexionDAO.em = ConexionDAO.emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```